# Get all <a> elements in a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there anyway I can get all of the `<a>` in a page, I want to apply a new targets to all of them.

Comment: to the person who downvoted this question: it does not deserve that. it is a clear question and a genuine problem. do not downvote because it is "2 n00bish 4 u".

Comment: You can grab any element you want either via the DOM or any of the *many* JS libraries out there: JQuery, Prototype, MooTools, ExtJS, Glow, YUI, Dojo, Mochikit, etc., etc.
Remember: Google is your friend.

Comment: @Geowa: That was me by accident. I tried to restore it to zero but that wasn't an option: I'd have ended up up-voting it... as indeed I now have.

Comment: @Coded Signal you can click the highlighted arrow to remove the vote

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
document.links
```

or in jQuery

```
$('a')
```

or in DOM

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')
```

Comment: +1 comprehensive; maybe add some help for modifying targets, even though it wasn't specifically asked for?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using jQuery:

```
$("a").attr("target","_blank")
```

Comment: i'm ok with you giving the jQuery solution as long as you give the non-jQuery solution as well. unless the asker mentions jQuery, jQuery should not be used as the main answer.

Comment: it was just a suggestion. i was providing help that i knew.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you need:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using purely Javascript DOM:

`var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");`

You can check out reference at: http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementmethods.shtml

Answer (score -2):

If I recall correctly, the prototype library has something like this...